# Detecting window size JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm trying to improve at JavaScript, I was trying to detect a window size when the page loads and of the page is resized, currently, I have tried

```
if(window.innerWidth > 500){
    'use strict';
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w > 500)
    {
        console.log("got here");
    }   
}
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    'use strict';
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if (w > 500)
    {
        console.log("got here");
    }
});
```

My main problem with this is it seems a little clunky, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not related to your question: why are you using `"use strict"` according to the condition (first snippet) and in a callback (second one)?

Comment: This question should probably go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh, I had read you should use `use strict` when doing "unsafe actions" I'd assumed a window resize might be classed as unsafe

Comment: Thanks, I will ask over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small refactoring:)

```
 'use strict';
    var minWidth = 500;

    toDoSomething();
    window.addEventListener("resize", toDoSomething);

    function toDoSomething(){
      if (window.innerWidth > minWidth){
        console.log("got here");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks